# google visualization api sum of a column

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is there any way to calculate sum of a column in table of google visualization API. For example in MS Excel there is feature for auto sum to calculate sum of a column. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only built-in aggregation functions are for [grouping data](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=en#google_visualization_data_group)

However, it is easy to write a function that will return the sum of a column in javascript.

For instance:

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Czech Republic', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany'],
    ['2003',  1336060,   3817614,       974066,       1104797,   6651824,  15727003],
    ['2004',  1538156,   3968305,       928875,       1151983,   5940129,  17356071],
    ['2005',  1576579,   4063225,       1063414,      1156441,   5714009,  16716049],
    ['2006',  1600652,   4604684,       940478,       1167979,   6190532,  18542843],
    ['2007',  1968113,   4013653,       1037079,      1207029,   6420270,  19564053],
    ['2008',  1901067,   6792087,       1037327,      1284795,   6240921,  19830493]
  ]);

  function getSum(data, column) {
    var total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++)
      total = total + data.getValue(i, column);
    return total;
  }

  alert(getSum(data, 1));
```

This will give you a nice alert box saying 9920627

1336060+1538156+1576579+1600652+1968113+1901067=9920627

Fiddle with the column number or use your own data table to make it all flexible-like.

Comment: thanks for your help and I want to display that SUM within the table like in MS Excel

Comment: Then just add it to the end of the table. While I am happy to help with concepts, I do expect you to actually do some of the work on your own...